Hydrogen atom energy: $n$ vs $l$ (QM)
I've come across a problem that states the following: let two (separate) particles be subject to a central potential $V(r)$. Their reduced radial function is depicted in the following image:


Which one of them has the greatest secondary quantum number ($l$)?
Which one of them has the greatest energy?

The first question is simple, since we know from solving the reduced radial equation for the central potential that solutions near the origin should behave as $R(r)\sim r^l$ and therefore the reduced radial function ($u(r)=rR(r)$) should behave as $u(r)\sim r^{l+1}$ near the origin. Hence, $l_a>l_b$ since the radial function in the second picture appears to be linear ($l_b=0$) and the one in the first image seems to be quadratic ($l_a=1$).
Nonetheless, when answering the second question, the solution states "since $l_a>l_b$, the potential well will be greater for particle A and therefore it must have a greater energy as well." However, I don't find this argument convincing: say these particles were electrons in their respective Hydrogen atoms, where energy only depends on the energy level ($n$) where the electron is. Electron A could be in the state $(2,1,0)$ and electron B could be in the state $(5,0,0)$, so electron B would be more energetic than electron A and still have a smaller $l$. Is the solution's reasoning correct? If so, what am I missing?

The number of nodes made sure that your bad case cannot happen.

@naturallyInconsistent right! Because $n=n_{nodes}+l+1$ for the Hydrogen atom, thanks for your answer. However, I don't know the general relation between $n,n_{nodes},l$ for every central potential, so I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer to question b)

You don't need $n$, you need the relation between $E$ and $\ell$ and the number of nodes for an unknown potential $V(r)$. So you need the relation between $E$ and the number of nodes for potential $V(r)+\frac{\ell_a(\ell_a+1)}{r^2}$, and for potential $V(r)+\frac{\ell_b(\ell_b+1)}{r^2}$. In both cases you need the second-lowest state (there is one node). Presumably that solves it. (Does a higher potential always have a higher second-lowest state than a lower potential?)
